# How to use standard input '<' in execl?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to achieve the equivalent of "`./myfile < input.txt`" using `execl()`:

```
execl("path/myfile", ",myfile", "< input.txt");

execl("/home/user/Desktop/Fuzzer/clear/easy_fuzzer/buf", "/home/user/Desktop/Fuzzer/clear/easy_fuzzer/buf", "buf < input", NULL);

execlp("/home/user/Desktop/Fuzzer/clear/easy_fuzzer/buf", "/home/user/Desktop/Fuzzer/clear/easy_fuzzer/buf", "input");
```

but the command fails...

I want 'input.txt' and '<' command through myfile using `execl` — how do I do it?

Comment: You can't. Redirection is a shell feature. You have to write the input to the program's input yourself.

Comment: Is there no way? i want to input to frok process scanf!

Comment: You open a pipe to the process, read the input file yourself and write to the process. That's what the shell does also. Or you can execute shell and tell it to run the command.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: What you describe is not what the shell does.  If you simply use `program < file`, the shell does not create any pipe; it opens the file for reading and ensures that the standard input of the program is read from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has to do the I/O redirection before you run the `execl()` code.
If you want to achieve the effect of a shell running:

```sh
/user/Desktop/Fuzzer/clear/easy_fuzzer/buf < input
```

then you will need to write something like this in the child code:

```c
const char *filename = "input";  // or "input.txt" — the question uses both
int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0)
    err_syserr("failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
    err_syserr("failed to redirect %s to standard input\n", filename);
close(fd);  // In theory, it could fail, but there isn't much you can do about it

const char *cmdpath = "/home/user/Desktop/Fuzzer/clear/easy_fuzzer/buf";
execl(cmdpath, "buf", (char *)NULL);
err_syserr("failed to execute program %s\n", cmdpath);
```

This should normally all be in the code executed by the child.

You can find the code for the `err_syserr()` function in `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` from https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.  One line error handling makes it less onerous than writing out multiple lines.  Note that there's no reason to check the return value from any of the `exec*()` functions.  If the function returns, it failed.  If it succeeds, there's a different process running in place of the current process.

If you like doing things the long-winded way, you can investigate whether your system supports [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) and its colleagues.  You can do all sorts of things by setting up appropriate sequences of attributes.  For my money, it is far simpler and clearer to write the code as shown above.

I would probably not use `execl()` — I'd probably use `execv()` (or perhaps `execvp()`) because it allows the argument list to be fixed at run-time instead of mandating that it is fixed at compile time.  The code passes `buf` as the value for `argv[0]` to the executed program.  If you want the full path name as `argv[0]` you can do that.

Note that if the file name part of the first argument to `execlp()` (or `execvp()`, or any other path-searching `exec*()` function) contains any `/` at all, then there is no path-based search performed, so it is not appropriate to use them if the command name is an absolute path name as in the example.